# Как можно ускорить чтение данных из SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Есть БД SQLite. Там около 400 значений, но поиск занимает пару секунд. Возможно ли сократить поиск до менее чем секунды, чтобы юзеру это не было заметно?
[Вот Гиста](https://gist.github.com/achatina/9d96951395ad8fbbbc63c0336095a246)

Comment: Пару секунд по всего 400 значениям?! Невероятно. Покажите DDL и запрос.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. ```
   c = myDbHelper.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
           show.setText(myDbHelper.getClassRoom(text));
       } while (c.moveToNext());
   }
   ```

   Вы бежите по запросу (400 записей) и 400 раз выполняете запрос `...where classroom = ?`. И 400 раз выводите одну и ту же информацию в `show`. Зачем вы это делаете? Достаточно только:

   ```
   show.setText(myDbHelper.getClassRoom(text));
   ```

   Кстати у вас sql-инъекция (`...where classRoom=\'"+ str + "\';"`). Пользуйтесь параметрами.
2. `SQLiteOpenHelper` предоставляет методы для создания `onCreate` и обновления `onUpgrade` БД, вызывать при этом по клику создание БД смысла нет никакого. Ваш метод `checkDataBase` не нужен, при вызове `onCreate` необходимо просто скопировать вашу базу (предварительно закрыв созданную helper'ом) - `copyDatabase`, также как вы делаете это в `onUpgrade`.

ЗЫ Если непонятно что вы напрограммировали, попробуйте разобраться с помощью отладчика и логирования.

Answer (score 5):

Проиндексируйте по полю `CLASSROOM`, а вообще советую в консоли запустить

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
```

[Читать здесь](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)

P.S. Оптимизация запросов или структуры БД напрямую не относится к Android - это как бы основы, которые предполагается, что прогер должен знать безотносительно оси, языка программирования, фреймворка и проч. наносных вещей.